# Loading image in Canvas with mouse follow

Tags: html5-canvas

I am struggling to make an image appear in a Canvas animated card. I can get text and drawn images to show up, but I can't seem to load the image and still have the ball follow the mouse. Why is that? I'm sure it's something super easy but I keep trying different things and am getting no where!

```
<script>

    var canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasPos = getPosition(canvas);
    var mouseX = 525;
    var mouseY = 325;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", setMousePosition, false);

    function setMousePosition(e) {
        mouseX = e.clientX - canvasPos.x;
        mouseY = e.clientY - canvasPos.y;
    }       

    function getPosition(el) {
        var xPosition = 0;
        var yPosition = 0;

        while (el) {
            xPosition += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
            yPosition += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
            el = el.offsetParent;
        }
        return {
            x: xPosition,
            y: yPosition
        };
    }    

    function loadTeacher() {
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.src = 'images/teacher.jpg';
    myImage.addEventListener("load", loadImage, false);

        function loadImage(e) {
        context.drawImage(myImage, 0, 75, 500, 350);
        } 
    } loadTeacher();

    function update() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        //write text
        context.font = "bold 12pt Helvetica, Ariel, sans-serif";
        context.textAlign = "center";
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.fillText("This teacher needs an apple now! Drag the apple to her mouth.", 250, 50);
        //draw circle
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.fill();

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }

    update();

  </script>
```

Comment: You must draw the image inside the update function. if not the image will be erased the next time the update function is called (context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)).

Comment: Ok, I get that and I'm trying to correct it but the image still won't show up. I've tried just calling the function inside update, aka loadTeacher(), putting the whole function inside the update function, etc and nothing seems to work.

Comment: finally got it to work! thanks!